# Long delay in using asyncio and websockets in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

I am experiencing a long (3-hour) delay (EDIT: the delay is brief at first and then gets longer throughout the day) in processing data pushed from a websocket server to my client.py. I know that it is not delayed by the server.

For example every 5 seconds I see the keep_alive log-event and its respective timestamp. So that runs smoothly. **But when I see a data frame processed in logs is actually 3 hours *after* when the server sent it.** Am I doing something to delay this process?

Am I calling my coroutine 'keep_alive' correctly? keep_alive is just a message to the server to keep the connection alive. The server echos the message back. Also am I logging too much? Could that be delaying the processing (I don't think so since I'm seeing the logging events occur right away).

```
async def keep_alive(websocket):
                """
                 This only needs to happen every 30 minutes. I currently have it set to every 5 seconds.
                """
                await websocket.send('Hello')   
                await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def open_connection_test():
    """
    Establishes web socket (WSS). Receives data and then stores in csv.
    """
    async with websockets.connect( 
            'wss://{}:{}@localhost.urlname.com/ws'.format(user,pswd), ssl=True, ) as websocket:
        while True:    
            """
            Handle message from server.
            """
            message = await websocket.recv()
            if message.isdigit():
                # now = datetime.datetime.now()
                rotating_logger.info ('Keep alive message: {}'.format(str(message)))
            else:
                jasonified_message = json.loads(message)
                for key in jasonified_message:
                    rotating_logger.info ('{}: \n\t{}\n'.format(key,jasonified_message[key]))    
                """
                Store in a csv file.
                """
                try:            
                    convert_and_store(jasonified_message)
                except PermissionError:
                    convert_and_store(jasonified_message, divert = True)                        
            """
            Keep connection alive.
            """            
            await keep_alive(websocket)

"""
Logs any exceptions in logs file.
"""
try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(open_connection())
except Exception as e:
    rotating_logger.info (e)
```

EDIT:
From the [documentation](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-websockets.protocol) - I'm thinking that this might have something to do with it - but I haven't connected the dots.

> The max_queue parameter sets the maximum length of the queue that
>   holds incoming messages. The default value is 32. 0 disables the
>   limit. Messages are added to an in-memory queue when they’re received;
>   then recv() pops from that queue. In order to prevent excessive memory
>   consumption when messages are received faster than they can be
>   processed, the queue must be bounded. If the queue fills up, the
>   protocol stops processing incoming data until recv() is called. In
>   this situation, various receive buffers (at least in asyncio and in
>   the OS) will fill up, then the TCP receive window will shrink, slowing
>   down transmission to avoid packet loss.

EDIT 9/28/2018: I'm testing it without the keep-alive message and that doesn't seem to be the issue. Could it be related to the convert_and_store() function? Does this need to be async def and then awaited as well?

```
def convert_and_store(data, divert = False, test = False):
    if test:
        data = b
    fields = data.keys()
    file_name =  parse_call_type(data, divert = divert)
    json_to_csv(data, file_name, fields)
```

EDIT 10/1/2018: It seems that both the keep-alive message and convert_and_store are both at issue; if I extend the keep-alive message to 60 seconds - then convert_and_store will run **only once per 60 seconds**. So convert_and_store is waiting on the keep_alive()...

Comment: Have you try simply `send` & `recv` a message, just like "Hello" and "Hello back"? Is the delay still occur?

Comment: Good point. That's actually what I'm doing with my 'keep alive' message. So that does not have a delay. But processing the actual (non-keep alive) messages and then appending them to the csv file is what gets more and more delayed throughout the day.

Comment: In this case, may be you can try using `multiprocessing`. Move the part for handling csv to a function and use `p = Process(target=my_function, args=argss)` to divert the task from the async-await, see if it can avoid the problem or not.

Comment: That sounds like a solid back up thanks. I'll look into the docs and test it. Without having any experience with multiprocessing I'd prefer to stick with the asyncio library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Could it be related to the convert_and_store() function?

Yes, it could be. Blocking code should not be called directly. If a function performs a CPU-intensive calculation for 1 second, all asyncio Tasks and IO operations would be delayed by 1 second.

An executor can be used to run a blocking code in a different thread/process:

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

def long_runned_job(x):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Done ", x)

async def test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        for i in range(5):
            loop.run_in_executor(pool, long_runned_job, i)
            print(i, " is runned")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test())
```

In your case it should look something like this:

```
import concurrent.futures

async def open_connection_test():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        async with websockets.connect(...) as websocket:
            while True:    
                ...
                loop.run_in_executor(pool, convert_and_store, args)
```

**EDITED**:

> It seems that both the keep-alive message and convert_and_store are both at issue

You can run `keep_alive` in background:

```
async def keep_alive(ws):
    while ws.open:
        await ws.ping(...)   
        await asyncio.sleep(...)

async with websockets.connect(...) as websocket:
    asyncio.ensure_future(keep_alive(websocket))
    while True:    
        ...
```

Comment: This, like @Kr98's example seems to still queue behind keep_alive(). What does this behavior tell you (from my EDIT): 10/1/2018: It seems that both the keep-alive message and convert_and_store are both at issue; if I extend the keep-alive message to 60 seconds - then convert_and_store will run only once per 60 seconds. So convert_and_store is waiting on the keep_alive()

Comment: @LiamHanninen you can run `keep_alive` in background. I have added an example to the answer

Comment: Awarding the bounty to you since you stuck to the asyncio library and help me learn about it - but I need to test before I mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Great this did the trick. Final question: "loop.run_in_executor(pool, convert_and_store, args)" seems to work with asyncio.ensure_future() like (asyncio.ensure_future(loop.run_in_executor(pool, convert_and_store, args))) as well as without asyncio.ensure_future(). Should I use asyncio.ensure_future() or no?

Comment: `run_in_executor` returns a `asyncio.Future` object, so `asyncio.ensure_future` is not required here

Comment: Just an fyi - I added a new question using the same code - about logging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708756/how-to-use-pythons-built-in-logging-with-asyncio-permission-error

Answer (score 1):

You **must** start a new thread for this `keep_alive()` function indeed.

For `async-await`, it is promising all tasks have been done before proceeding to next step.

Thus, `await keep_alive(websocket)` actually block the thread in this sense. You may not await the `keep_alive` here such that the process can continue but for sure, that is not what you want, I sure.

Actually, what you want is two time-frame, one for communicate with server, one for keep server alive. They should be separated as they are in different coroutine.

So, the correct way is using `Thread`, and don't need to use `asyncio` in this case, keep things simple.

First, change `keep_alive()` into following.

```
def keep_alive():
    """
        This only needs to happen every 30 minutes. I currently have it set to every 5 seconds.
    """
    while True:
        websocket.send('Hello') 
        time.sleep(1)
```

In `open_connection_test()`

```
async def open_connection_test():
    """
    Establishes web socket (WSS). Receives data and then stores in csv.
    """
    thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_alive, args=())
    thread.daemon = True   # Daemonize
    thread.start()
    async with websockets.connect(...) as websocket:
        ....
        #No need this line anymore.
        #await keep_alive(websocket)
```

Comment: Thanks! keep_alive needs websocket as an argument. And so it would have to go after the async with websockets.connect(...) as websocket: Would that be an issue for using threading.Thread()?

Comment: @LiamHanninen, no problem, thx to GIL it won't cause any problem, and indeed the asyncio ans you chosen is doing the same thing. But I do recommend using `Thread` instead of `asyncio`, as doing background task is not purpose of `asyncio`.

Comment: Thanks - will circle back to this if my long-term testing doesn't pan out. I'm currently getting a 1006 error after 30 minutes. What or who is GIL?

Comment: @LiamHanninen,  GIL stands for Global Interpreter Lock, which means only one thread can control the python interpreter at a time. So using `Thread` is guaranteed thread safe, in this case you do not need to pickle `websockect` like in multiprocessing . While, `asyncio` is not guaranteed thread safe (though there is thread-safe method in `asyncio` library).

Comment: Just an fyi - I added a new question using the same code - about logging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708756/how-to-use-pythons-built-in-logging-with-asyncio-permission-error

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be more clear,Use `ThreadPoolExecutor` make  blocking code running in background

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

def convert_and_store(data, divert=False, test=False):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(pool, _convert_and_store, divert, test)


def _convert_and_store(data, divert=False, test=False):
    if test:
        data = b
    fields = data.keys()
    file_name = parse_call_type(data, divert=divert)
    json_to_csv(data, file_name, fields)
```

asyncio send keep alive msg demo

```
async def kepp_alive(websocket):
    while True:
        await websocket.send_str(ping)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it is still hanging up on the keep-alive message (see EDIT that I will add in a minute). But, like my original script, this still waits until the keep-alive message executes before running.

Comment: I suggest you use asyncio send keep alive msg , I will edit my anwser